# Convert django request.body (bytes) into json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a class based view in which a put function and trying to get request.body into json.

```
from django.views import View
import json
class StudentView(View):
    def put(self, request):
        body = request.body #b'name=Arpita+kumari+Verma&roll=109&city=USA'
        json_body = json.loads(body) # JSONError 'expecting dict values but given bytes object'
        # I want something like this
        # {
        #      'name':'Arpita kumari Verma',
        #      'roll':109,
        #      'city':'USA',
        # }
        json_dumped_data = json.dumps(json_body)
        return HttpResponse(json_dumped_data, content_type="application/json")
```

my requests app

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/student/'
json_data = {
    'name':'Arpita kumari Verma',
    'roll':109,
    'city':'USA'
}
results = requests.put(url, json_data)
```

Comment: replace`json.loads(body)` with `json.loads(body.decode())`

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: check your http request, it happens when http body is `None`, you can add `try except` to deal with it.

Comment: ok, i found out that `#b'name=Arpita+kumari+Verma&roll=109&city=USA'` is not json string at all, can you provide your `http url`and `body`?

Comment: here i added my requests app for you, however i am able to get request.body in bytes format, so its not `none`.

Comment: replace `results = requests.put(url, json_data)` with `results = requests.put(url, json=json_data)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because in requests.put you not sending json, but form data. You can send json in requests.put or convert request.body into `QueryDict` and do something like that:

`json.dumps(dict(QueryDict(request.body)))`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this,

```
json_data_recieved = request.POST
# this method can be used in every request methods (post, put, patch, delete)
# except get (user request.GET for get methods)
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
body = request.body
json_body = json.loads(body)
```

with

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
json_body = json.loads(body_unicode)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`userdict = json.loads(str(request.body,encoding='utf-8'))`
This is the correct way